# More text and more blank at the bottom of UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cell, sizetofit

the UITextView is in a static cell in UITableViewController, and add code `descriptionText.sizeToFit()` so that the cell height can fit the text.

the cell works fine with few text input, when more text it gets, the blank at the bottom of the cell becomes heigher too.

I had tried to add code `descriptionText.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`, not work either.

Any help? Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Update: 
Weird things, when runs on ios8, it still shows the blank, BUT when scrolling to the bottom so that the cells hidden, and then scrolling back to top, THE BLANK DISPEARED! it means it works in normal. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it: By calculating the height of each UITextView and returning the height (+padding if you want) in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *body = self.messages[indexPath.row];
    CGRect rect = [body boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([width of your UITextViews], CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:[Font Size]} context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: No. it doesn't work. constraints had been set before, when I use `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, it shows only the default height(30) which can't show the whole text. By now, the cell can adjust the height to show the whole text, but just also shows more blank. :-(

Comment: I updated my answer with another way to do it. I've used this myself and it should work.

Comment: Armin, thanks your suggestion. When running the codes, first I got 'CGFLOAT_MAX' is unavailable: use CGFloat.max, so I use 'height: 10000.0 instead. and cannot use '|' in swift, so use only .UsesLineFragmentOrigin. It's work! BUT... depends on the font size. The font size is set to 14 in IB, for a better height of the textview, font size must be set to 12.5 in codes. Although it's a better way to solve the problem, but I don't think it's the best one.

Comment: temporarily using `height/1.22` to handle it. :-(

Comment: Weird things, when runs on ios8, it still shows the blank, BUT when scrolling to the bottom so that the cells hidden, and then scrolling back to top, THE BLANK DISPEARED! it means it works in normal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the view not to auto-adjust the insets:

The documentation says:

> If you don’t want a scroll view’s content insets to be automatically
>   adjusted, set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO. (The default
>   value of automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is YES.)

So you have to add the following line of code to your viewDidLoad:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

Or you could just override the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` - method and return `false`.

Comment: I have to say it fails to work too, though many guys said this solution solve the blank at the top. When adding `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` , the cell at the top even hidden under the navigation bar. Do you think it's a problem of insets? it's odd that the blank could be increased by the text.